# Needing advice on structuring a larger scale batch file game

Tags: templates, batch-file, cmd, architecture, macros

So I've started getting familiar with Batch for the last year off and on, all self taught, and I've made a few little dinky projects here and there but I'm wanting to find out the best way to go about expanding my code. Using other programs for inspiration I've learned just the tip of the icebergs for "FOR loops" and using functions and small macro processes. I want to know if there is anything I should do differently in terms of architecture and planning so I can one day make amazing Batch programs like T3RROR (little weird but I'm a big fan and your my batch idol).

Below is my most complex batch code I've written and a template for future games, please add any tip or advice.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
title crafting micro
color 2
:://///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
:pre_start
::initializes at the start of the program
set /a display_message=0
set /a inv_fiber=1
set /a fiber_qty=100
set /a inv_rope=0
set /a rope_qty=0
set /a inv_stick=1
set /a stick_qty=100
set /a inv_stone=1
set /a stone_qty=100
set /a inv_sharpened_stone=0
set /a sharpened_stone_qty=0
set /a inv_spear=0
set /a spear_qty=0
set /a inv_handaxe=0
set /a handaxe_qty=0
set /a inv_hammer=0
set /a hammer_qty=0
:://///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
:start
cls
echo ----------------------------------------------------
echo         Crafting Menu
echo ----------------------------------------------------
echo.
echo Raw materials
echo -------------
if %inv_fiber%==1 echo Fiber: x%fiber_qty%
if %inv_stick%==1 echo Stick: x%stick_qty%
if %inv_stone%==1 echo Stone: x%stone_qty%
echo.
echo Refined Materials
echo -----------------
if %inv_rope%==1 echo Rope: x%rope_qty%
if %inv_sharpened_stone%==1 echo Sharpened Stone: x%sharpened_stone_qty%
echo.
echo Tools
echo -----
if %inv_spear%==1 echo Spear: x%spear_qty%
if %inv_handaxe%==1 echo Handaxe: x%handaxe_qty%
if %inv_hammer%==1 echo Hammer: x%hammer_qty%
::sets visibility
echo.
echo ----------------------------------------------------
echo.
echo What do you wanna craft?
echo 1. Rope (x3 Fiber)
echo 2. Sharpened Stone (x2 Stones)
echo 3. Spear (x1 Rope, x1 Stick, x1 Sharpened Stone )
echo 4. Handaxe (x2 Rope, x2 Stick, x1 Sharpened Stone)
echo 5. Hammer (x2 Rope, x2 Stick, x1 Stone)
echo.
choice /c 12345
echo.
echo.

if %errorlevel%==1 (
    set item=Rope
    ::item being crafted
    set /a req1=%fiber_qty%
    ::1st required item
    set /a min1=3
    :: minimum amount needed to craft
    set /a req2=0
    set /a min2=0
    set /a req3=0
    set /a min3=0
    set var1=fiber
    ::passes a string to be use for a vavriable
    set var2=
    set var3=
    set var4=rope
)
if %errorlevel%==2 (
    set item='Sharpened Stone'
    set /a req1=%stone_qty%
    set /a min1=2
    set /a req2=0
    set /a min2=0
    set /a req3=0
    set /a min3=0
    set var1=stone
    set var2=
    set var3=
    set var4=sharpened_stone
)
if %errorlevel%==3 (
    set item=Spear
    set /a req1=%rope_qty%
    set /a min1=1
    set /a req2=%stick_qty%
    set /a min2=1
    set /a req3=%sharpened_stone_qty%
    set /a min3=1
    set var1=rope
    set var2=stick
    set var3=sharpened_stone
    set var4=spear
)
if %errorlevel%==4 (
    set item=Handaxe
    set /a req1=%rope_qty%
    set /a min1=2
    set /a req2=%stick_qty%
    set /a min2=2
    set /a req3=%sharpened_stone_qty%
    set /a min3=1
    set var1=rope
    set var2=stick
    set var3=sharpened_stone
    set var4=handaxe
)
if %errorlevel%==5 (
    set item=Hammer
    set /a req1=%rope_qty%
    set /a min1=2
    set /a req2=%stick_qty%
    set /a min2=2
    set /a req3=%stone_qty%
    set /a min3=1
    set var1=rope
    set var2=stick
    set var3=stone
    set var4=hammer
)
::////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
:craftable_check
if %req1% GEQ %min1% (  
    if %req2% GEQ %min2% (
        if %req3% GEQ %min3% (
        ::checks minimum requried material inventory for crafting
            set /a %var1%_qty=!%var1%_qty!-%min1%
            set /a %var2%_qty=!%var2%_qty!-%min2%
            set /a %var3%_qty=!%var3%_qty!-%min3%
            ::uses all the required inventory for crafting
            set /a %var4%_qty=!%var4%_qty!+1
            ::creates the crafted item
            set /a inv_%var4%=1
            ::makes the new item is visible
            if %req1% LEQ 0 (
                set inv_%var1%=0
            )
            if %req2% LEQ 0 (
                set inv_%var2%=0
            )
            if %req3% LEQ 0 (
                set inv_%var3%=0
            )
            ::makes the items ivisible if there is no inventory
            set /a display_message=1
            set message='You have successfully created a %item%!'
            goto message
        )
    )
)
set /a display_message=1
set message=You dont have enough material for this
goto message
:://///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
:message
cls
if %display_message%==1 (
    echo %message%
    pause
    set /a display_message=0
    goto start
)
```

```
::General Settings ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@echo off
title Game Template
color 02
cd "%userprofile%\desktop"

::Game Settings ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:game_settings
cls

goto welcome

::Welcome Screen --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:welcome
cls
echo Welcome to this Game!
echo/
echo Please select one of the options below
echo 1. New Game
echo 2. Load Game
echo 3. Credits

choice /c 123
if %errorlevel%==1 goto back_story
if %errorlevel%==2 goto load_game
if %errorlevel%==3 goto credits

goto welcome

::Save Game -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:save_game
cls

(
echo %location%
echo %player_name%
)>"GameSave.txt"

echo Game saved...
pause

goto :eof

::Load Game -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:load_game
cls

(
set /p location=
set /p player_name=
)<"GameSave.txt"
pause

goto %location%

::Back Story ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:back_story
cls

echo Backstory...
pause >nul

goto character_creation

::Character Creation ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
:character_creation
cls

echo What is your name?

set /p player_name=
if /i "%player_name%"=="" (
    echo Player name can not be blank.
    pause >nul
    goto character_creation
)
goto start

::Game Start ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:start
cls

set location=start

echo %player_name%
echo %location%
echo/
echo 1. Pause Menu

choice /c 1
if %errorlevel%==1 goto pause_menu

goto start

::Pause Menu ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:pause_menu
cls

echo 1. Save Game
echo 2. Return
echo 3. Quit

choice /c 123
if %errorlevel%==1 call :save_game
if %errorlevel%==2 goto %location%
if %errorlevel%==3 goto exit

goto pause_menu

::Credits ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:credits
cls

echo credits...
pause >nul

goto welcome
```

Comment: If your code works and you just want our thoughts on it, you might want to ask on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead. That said, I see that you're using `::` for comments inside of parentheses, and that can sometimes break things, so you should use `REM` there instead.

Comment: Thanks I apricate the redirect. As for the comments I'll try to stay away from that then I just dislike how ugly the REM looks lol.

Comment: Before you post at [codereview.se], make sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *does*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".  Be sure that the code works correctly; include your unit tests if possible.  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.

Comment: Well I shouldn't've uploaded that so quickly then it seems. Ill update my post then. Thank you for the tip!

Comment: Lines `8` through `24` are all incorrectly using an option for arithmetic i.e.`/A`. No arithmetic is being perfomed, so you should be using just `Set`, e.g. ```Set "display_message=0"```. The only acceptable way to use the `/A` option in that case would be like this: ```Set /A display_message=inv_rope=rope_qty=inv_sharpened_stone=sharpened_stone_qty=inv_spear=spear_qty=inv_handaxe=handaxe_qty=inv_hammer=hammer_qty=0```, ```Set /A inv_fiber=inv_stick=inv_stone=1```, ```Set /A fiber_qty=stick_qty=stone_qty=100```.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense i was under the impression that it was anything that could be arithmetic, Thank you for correcting me!

Comment: Hi there Dean - Glad to see an interest in the idea of planning out a game, it's something not many new batch scriptors consider doing. Stackoverflow isn't really the place for discussion or general advice questions though, the `dostips.com` forum or a discord server like `server.bat` is a better place for discussions on things to consider when planning a project or what effecient or easy to adapt methods exist for doing things.

Comment: Oh! Perfect, I will go check these out! Thank you so much. I've always enjoyed reading and studying your code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    if %req3% GEQ %min3% (
    ::checks minimum requried material inventory for crafting
        set /a %var1%_qty=!%var1%_qty!-%min1%
```

won't work properly - `::` comments are actually broken labels (labels that cannot be reached with a `goto`) and break code blocks (parenthesised series of statements)

Reserve a prefix character for any variable that you may want to save to a file for reloading later. EG `#`

```
set #>filename
```

saves all of the variables that start `#` to the file in the form `#whatever=something`.

Reload with

```
for /f "delims=" %%e in (filename) do set "%%e"
```

Equally, you can set up scenario files by choosing another prefix character.

Clearing the current values of variables-beginning-# is

```
for/f "delims==" %%e in ('set # 2^>nul') do set "%%e="
```

which you do just before loading from file.

---

Use `set "var=value"` for setting string values - this avoids problems caused by trailing spaces. Don't assign a terminal `\`, Space or `"` - build pathnames from the elements - counterintuitively, it is likely to make the process easier. If the syntax `set var="value"` is used, then the quotes become part of the value assigned.

---

set up a menu subroutine using `choice`

```
:menu
set "choices="
set /a choicecount=0
cls
:menu_next
set /a choicecount+=1
if defined choicetext[%choicecount%] echo %choicecount%. choicetext[%choicecount%]&set "choices=%choices%%choicecount%"
if %choicecount% lss 9 goto menunext
echo Q. Quit
choice /c q%choices% /N /M "%~1"
goto :eof
```

This way, you can set up the available choices in `choicetext[?]` (and clear them with

```
for/f "delims==" %%e in ('set choicetext[ 2^>nul') do set "%%e="
```

) then display the menu by executing

```
call :menu "Some message"
```

When `:menu" returns, you can then

```
GOTO Someplace%errorlevel%
```

which will `goto someplace2` etc. Note that because `q` is always the first character of the `choices`, then `q` will always return `errorlevel 1`, hence the label `:whatever1` will mean `q was pressed`. That way, you don't need to alter the `quit` code should you extend the menu.

(X for eXit works, too.)

Comment: Time to get to work! I think I understood most of that let me see if I cant improve what is here with the direction given thank you!