# how would i implement a form of level identification in my batch game (batch)

Tags: batch-file

I've got some rough code for a revive function I'm making for a batch game but I'm not sure how I would make it so I can go to any specified level after reviving. i would rather not copy the code for each level so I want to know if there is a easier way

im reletivly new to batch coding so im not sure what to try but this is the rough idea

```
:lvl(1)
(somehow identify this level as a integer or something)
(if character dies during this lvl they would go to revive)


:lvl(2)
(somehow identify this level as a integer or something)
(if character dies during this lvl they would go to revive)


:revive
cls
echo do you want to revive
echo 1.yes
echo 2.no
CHOICE /C 12 /m "choose an option"
  IF ERRORLEVEL 2 goto dead
  IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto ?
(this is where i want an identifier for each lvl so i can easily send the user to the lvl they're on)
```

Comment: use a variable holding the `level` number, and use: `goto:level[%level%]`
- note: avoid using parentheses where not required as they have special meaning in batch files.

Comment: @T3RR0R Could you make an example on how I would do that like I said I’m very new to batch coding

Comment: `set lvl=1`, `if %lvl% == 1 goto ...`. See `set /?` and `if /?`

Comment: Tips: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74414337/2128947

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
set /a level = 0
```

You could also define it as a normal variable, it doesn't matter

As for your revive, code just use if statements like so:

```
IF %level% == 1 goto :level(1)
IF %level% == 2 goto :level(2)
```

If you have trouble with this, you find documentation at [Microsoft's Learn Page](https://learn.microsoft.com)